# What to include when packaging a mobile app in Flash?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, publishing

I'm just experimenting with building an app in Flash Pro, and when it comes to publishing the files it gives me the option to +include additional files.

Would I be right in assuming that this means image folders, com folders etc and any other files typically associated with building an as3 project?

Also is it not best to write the code inline within the main file to reduce the additional external as3 files?

Hoping anyone can give me an insight as the documentation I have found seems a little vague at best practice for this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Would I be right..." — No. You should include files that you will use in code: images, icons, audio/video files, XML/JSON files. "is it not best to write..." — No. Create as many .as files as you need. Sorry for the short answer. Maybe someone will write more detail.

Comment: Thanks @subdan, so basically I include anything relative to the root folder of my app. Seems obvious enough I just wasn't sure if that would be included in the publish.